# Decoder for binary files in C

Tags: c, binary, decode

I need to decode text from binary files and compare it with text(which is written by user) in my program and also I need to decode text to binary text.
Example:

1. 011011000110111101101100 => sometext
2. sometext => 011011000110111101101100

It should be 2 functions.
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: You can convert a "numeric" string written in a number base to `long` with `strtol`.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it, i try to find something in the internet, but i can only find how to decode numbers, but i need text as well

Comment: Can you give an example for "decode text from binary files", e.g. do you mean to decode it into an integer or long? can you show what for your two functions you are looking for is the input and what the output, respectively?

Comment: Even your example is useless, since both sides of the `=>` show the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, so here's how it works :

- You need a function can convert 8 bits binary's numbers (can add '0' after the numbers to always have 8bits), every numbers you get can be converted with ASCII table, for exemple l is 108, I assume you already know
- an other function can convert ASCII characters to 8bits binary's numbers

Binary to Decimal :

```
01101100 -> 0.2^0 + 0.2^1 + 1.2^2 + 1.2^3 + 0.2^4 + 1.2^5 + 1.2^6 + 0.2^7
```

it's very easy

Decimal to Binary :
Get the rest and the quotient :

```
108/2 : q = 54 r = 0
54/2  : q = 27 r = 0
27/2  : q = 13 r = 1
13/2  : q = 6  r = 1
6/2   : q = 3  r = 0
3/2   : q = 1  r = 1
```

take the last quotient and all rest : 1101100, add a 0 to have 8 bits : 01101100